# Renaming files based on a string

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk, grep

i have a some files that needs to renamed with a string/pattern

```
actual file  : CCRD_LLX_814_20160218043477.EDI814


Rename files to: actual file. XHS.JOBRUNID.%INTERFACENAME%.actualfile.XHE
```

i have two types of INTERFACENAME:

```
 814 = EB_ENROLL_REQ
    810 = EB_BCHG_REQ
```

so if the actual file name has 814 in it then i have to rename the file as:

```
CCRD_LLX_814_20160218043477.EDI814.XHS.JOBRUNID.EB_ENROLL_REQ.CCRD_LLX_814_20160218043477.EDI814.XHE
```

if the actual file name has 810 in it then the file will be

```
CCRD_LLX_810_20160218043477.EDI814.XHS.JOBRUNID.EB_BCHG_REQ.CCRD_LLX_810_20160218043477.EDI814.XHE
```

Tried:

```
rename 's/^/Interface_Name/g' filename
```

But didnt worked out.please assist

Comment: Hy am sorry,thanks for the solution but am expecting reading file names dynamically probably with sed/awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A harmless `bash` script which does this simple task. This is based on the assumption that the last 3 characters in the filename determining which INTERFACE NAME to use.

```
#!/bin/bash

inputString=$1

# Bash built-in parameter substitution to get the last 3 characters from the string
pattern=${inputString: -3} 

declare -a myArray

myArray[814]=EB_ENROLL_REQ  # Mapping the INTERFACE NAME array
myArray[810]=EB_BCHG_REQ

mv -v "$inputString" "$inputString.XHS.JOBRUNID.${myArray[$pattern]}.$inputString.XHE"
```

Run the script as follows:-

```
$ ./rename_script.sh CCRD_LLX_814_20160218043477.EDI814
`CCRD_LLX_814_20160218043477.EDI814` -> `CCRD_LLX_814_20160218043477.EDI814.XHS.JOBRUNID.EB_ENROLL_REQ.CCRD_LLX_814_20160218043477.EDI814.XHE`
```